# Split image files with bash

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have no idea how I could do this so I'd love some help. I have images that need to be copied and have a new file name applied to them based on the current file naming. Here is an example of some of the files:

> alternate8_1045205_1037121_1037063_1037122.tif
>   alternate5_1207024_1207037_1207023_1226394_1207036.tif
>   standard_lifestyle_1037098_1037044_1037099.tif
>   standard_lifestyle_1045200_1037117_1037056_1037118.tif

I need to:

1) Make a copy of the file for each number in the original file name, eg. for the first one I need alternate8_1045205.tif, alternate8_1037121.tif, alternate8_1037063.tif, alternate8_1037122.tif

2) For the files with multiple words as well as numbers, I need files for each word + number, eg. standard_1045205.tif, lifestyle_1045205.tif etc.

I'd be looking to run something in Terminal, maybe bash. I've tried to figure out how to do this using regex but it's tricky because the amount of numbers and words varies. Some files only have 3 numbers, one file has 22! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each filename to a list, and then loop through the list:

```
namelist=()
numlist=()
for f in $(ls); do
    alllist=$(echo ${f%.tif} | tr '_' '\n')
    for e in ${alllist[*]}; do
        if [[ $e == *[a-zA-Z]* ]]; then
             namelist+=($e)
        else
             numlist+=($e)
        fi
    done

    for name in ${namelist[*]}; do
        for num in ${numlist[*]}; do
            echo ${name}_${num}
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use python to do the actual text processing.

```
def splitToFilenames(filename):
    first = []
    second = []
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    for word in filename.split(".")[0].split("_"):
        if word.isdigit():
            second.append(word)
        else:
            first.append(word)
    return ["{}_{}.{}".format(name,num,extension) for name in first for num in second]
```

This is less error prone, and easier to maintain. Also, it will work on all systems. 
The above function will give out a list of new file names. Use this list to copy the original file into new ones.